# Webpack build is throwing ".sourceMap is an alias for .sourceMaps, cannot use both"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, source-maps

I have upgraded babel to below versions in reactjs application. 
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0", 
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2", 
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",

After this my webpack build is failing with below error

ERROR in ./src/App.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 0)
.sourceMap is an alias for .sourceMaps, cannot use both

I am not sure where to remove sourceMap/s, i am not using any sourcemap in babel.config.js and I have removed devtool from webpack.config.js
Can you please help?